# expected value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Update**

I am working on returning the expected value E[x^2]. I have already created the function *normal* to sample normal values with mean mu and sigma2. I want to use this function to generate normal values and then apply *fun* to each of those values. Do I need to define expected value in my loop and then apply *fun*? Can I take the mean after I find x^2 for each x? Here's what I've been working on:

```
def fun(x):
    y=x**2
    return y

def EV(fun,n_samples,mu,sigma2):
        for i in range(1,n_samples):
```

...             u= np.random.uniform(0,1,1)
...             output.append(float(y))
...     return output

Comment: `fun` is just a function. You can put `response.append(fun(normal(n_samples,mu,sigma2))` . Is that your question? Note that `i` is not used by `normal`, so it doesn't need to be in the loop

Answer (score 5):

You're doing a Monte-Carlo experiment, estimating the expected value of the square of a normally distributed random number. To do this you need only accumulate the sum of the squares of the pseudorandom deviates and then divide by the number of them.

```
>>> import random
>>> n_samples = 100
>>> sum_x_2 = 0
>>> for i in range(n_samples):
...     sum_x_2 += random.normalvariate(0,1)**2
...     
>>> estimate = sum_x_2 / n_samples
>>> estimate
1.045308497590742
```

I've used standard normal deviates.

Another way of doing this in Python is to use a library that will attempt to perform computer algebra.

```
>>> from sympy.stats import E, Normal
>>> Z = Normal('Z', 0, 1)
>>> E(Z**2)
1
```

The Monte Carlo didn't do so badly given that I allowed so few samples.